# Can you use »müssen« to express an assumption?

Tags: modal-verb

In English, I might say something like "You must be sad" to someone whose friend had died, which means something more like "I assume you are sad", rather than "You have to be sad".

Does the same work in German? Could I say "Du musst traurig sein"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it works. You can weaken the sentence a little, if you use Konjuktiv II. Here are some more examples:

> Der Motor ist noch heiß, sie muss gerade angekommen sein. **(100% certainty)**
>
> Du hast im Lotto gewonnen, du musst jetzt sehr glücklich sein. **(100% certainty)**
>
> Es ist schon zwei Uhr, er müsste gleich kommen. **(90% certainty)**

Comment: Doesn't Konjunktive II express that something is unlikely?

Comment: @user251257 no, you cannot generalize it that way. It expresses, that something is less likely. Typically, it expresses a *possibility*, whereas the standard form expresses *facts*.

Comment: @user251257: Konjunktive expresses "uncertainty," not "unlikely." Even "90% certain" has enough uncertainty (10%) for Konjunktive

Comment: @TomAu: The subjunctive II (Konjunktiv II) does neither **generally** express uncertainty nor unlikelikelihood – it expresses irreality or impossibility. Only with some modal verbs *(müssen, dürfen, sollen),* it shifts their meaning towards expressing likelihood.